# Required Drop Down Box in html5 form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Following is my code from dropdown. I am trying to make sure that person has to select option from dropdown but not "Please select an option...". I can submit form without giving me error. I want to sent error that please select option if person has not selected any option from dropdown.

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label name="ContactType">Contact Type:</label>
    <select class="form-control" name="ContactType" pattern".{3,}">
        <option value="Phone">Phone</option>
        <option value="Meeting">Meeting</option>
        <option value="None">None</option>
        <option value="" selected disabled>Please select an option...</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

New in HTML. What should I do ? I don't mind using jquery or javascript for solution.

Thanks

Comment: <option value="" selected disabled>Please select an option...</option> get that first

Comment: This is a slightly different question than the "duplicate" question that was linked.  He's not asking for the "placeholder" experience, just forcing a selection.

Comment: Above code send me no information if i don't select option from dropdown. I want to force person to select option.

Comment: Anyway, the answer is to add the `required` attribute to your `select` element.  As noted on MDN (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/select), `required - A Boolean attribute indicating that an option with a non-empty string value must be selected.`  Since your default selection has an empty string as a value, selecting it will not meet the "required" check.